# How to use switch case with String.Contains?

Tags: c#

I want to use `switch` `case` for the code below. Is this possible, and if so, how?

```
private IEnumerable<string> GetRowValues(DataRow dr)
{
    foreach (DataColumn col in DataResult.Columns)
        yield return replaceSpecialChar(dr[col].ToString());
}

private string replaceSpecialChar(string text)
{
    if (text.Contains("<"))
    {
        text = text.Replace("<", "&lt;");
    }
    else if (text.Contains(">"))
    {
        text = text.Replace(">", "&gt;");
    }
    else if (text.Contains("<=")){
        text = text.Replace("<=", "&le;");
    }
    else if (text.Contains(">="))
    {
        text = text.Replace(">=","&ge;");
    }
    return text;
}
```

Comment: You can't -- your use of `if / else if` is the best approach

Comment: That said, there's no point in the `Contains` tests -- `Replace` will do nothing if the string doesn't contain the character to be replaced. So you can just write `return text.Replace("<", "&lt;").Replace(">", "&gt;")...`

Comment: Are those the only ones you need replaced or do you actually want to ["HTMLEncode"](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.webutility.htmlencode?view=net-5.0#System_Net_WebUtility_HtmlEncode_System_String_)?

Comment: You probably shouldn't have if/elses. It seems weird to me that if there are any < characters you only replace those and not any > characters. I would think that you'd want to replace both < and >.

Comment: @canton7 To be pedantic, such a change would change the semantics of what the code is doing. However, I think the code as presented is likely buggy and would indeed be fixed by that change.

Answer (score 5):

The quick answer is, you can't use `switch` to do what you want and you shouldn't try to either. In it's current form if your string contains more than one of the symbols, then only the first one it matches will get replaced.

You also need to be careful about the order you do these in as `<=` would end up being `&lt=`. You're also missing a trailing semi-colon for `"&lt"` and `"&gt"`

What you should do instead is just chain multiple calls to `.Replace()`

```
private string replaceSpecialChar(string text)
{
    return text
        .Replace("<=", "&le;")
        .Replace(">=", "&ge;")
        .Replace("<", "&lt;")
        .Replace(">", "&gt;");
}
```

Answer (score 2):

As some already said: You can't change this to a switch as you can't use functions for cases, exception some simple conditions with newer C# versions.

Aside of that your code looks like you want to replace all your given special chars with html code replacements. Your code currently only replaces the first special chars that fits one of your conditions and not all of it.

Also the if/else if parts are not required if you want to replace all given characters with your html codes. Simply use this instead:

```cs
return text.Replace("<=", "&le;")
    .Replace(">=", "&ge;")
    .Replace("<", "&lt;")
    .Replace(">", "&gt;");
```

*Edit seems like phuzi was quicker, and also mentions the order of replacing your characters ;)

Comment: But do note that this changes the semantics of the original code. In the original code, if the text contains "<" then any ">" would NOT be changed - but your code WILL change them. However, I think this is because the original has a bug which your code is fixing (but not fixing the order-of-replacement bug)

Comment: Yes, this will replace all occurences of those given characters, as stated in the answer this might be the question creator's desired solution, but mistakenly implemented.

If not, then yes, reuse the "if/else if" implementation shown on the question